# Qt lineEdit -> QListWidget colored

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

So with the code below I want to write a value (Money) in a `LineEdit`. Then I push a `pushbutton` and the text should appear in a `QListWidget`.

If I get Money, it should appear green, if I waste Money, it should appear red.

The Code so far (make it double for both possibilities:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString value;
    value = ui->lineEdit->text();
    ui->listWidget->addItem(value);
}
```

My most reced try looks like this:

```
QListWidget w;
w.item(0)->setForeground(Qt::green);
```

But the program collapse when I use this.

Comment: `w.item(0)->setForeground(Qt::green);` -- Break this up into two separate lines and check if `w.item(0)` actually returns a valid instance.  BTW, you should *always* do this if you're chaining calls like this, and something crashes.  Make sure you know which link in the chain is causing the issue.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply :)
the debugger said:
  inline void setForeground(const QBrush &brush)
        { setData(Qt::ForegroundRole, brush); }

And im afraight I dont know what you mean with "break up in two lines. How do i write it?

Comment: Look at that line of code.  You have `w.item(0)`.  What does that return?  Is it valid?  If it isn't valid, then there is no way `w.item(0)->setForeground()` is going to work.  Like I said, if you have something looking like this `a()->b()->c()->d()` and it crashes, what caused the crash, `a()`, `b()`, `c()`, or `d()`?  You won't know until break up that one line into separate calls and test each one.

Comment: @Noodlez remove `QListWidget w;
w.item(0)->setForeground(Qt::green);` and use `QListWidgetItem *it = ui->listWidget->item(0); if(it) it->setForeground(Qt::green);`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
Now I got you, will keep that in mind for the future, thanks :) You were right, it didnt work.

Comment: @eyllanesc
It works O_o
Dont know how but it works just fine^^
Will try to understand your code. Thanks :)

Comment: @eyllanesc just figured that the color will be lost as soon as i push a second value.
After I push a second value the first value will appear just black. How couldI fix that?

Comment: @Noodlez Do you think that magically the QListWidget you created visually is obtained when you use `QListWidget w;`?, And if you had 2 QListWidget to which they referred to with `QListWidget w;` ?, then in programming nothing is magic, to access You have to do an element correctly, that's your problem.

Comment: @Noodlez I do not understand you, if you want help you will have to make an effort to provide a [mcve]